# SVG плюс CSS анимация

Tags: css, анимация, svg, css-animation

Я хочу сделать анимацию волны, которая превращается в прямую линию.
То, что  есть сейчас, это анимация волны, идущей слева направо, см. ниже код. Также это может быть сделано только с помощью CSS?

```css
body {
  width: 960px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
}


/*#wave1 {
  transform: translate(-260px, 200px);
}*/

#wave1 {
  animation: popup 5s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes popup {
  0% {
    transform: translate( -500px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(400px, 0);
  }
}

#wave2 {
  animation: popup 5s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes popup {
  0% {
    transform: translate( -500px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(400px, 0);
  }
}

#wave3 {
  animation: popup 5s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes popup {
  0% {
    transform: translate( -500px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(400px, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="960px" height="200px" viewBox="91.43 -87.5 960 200" overflow="visible" enable-background="new 91.43 -87.5 960 200" xml:space="preserve">
  <path id="wave1" fill="none" stroke="#2E2925" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M0,24.5c28.57,0,28.57-24,57.141-24c28.57,0,28.57,24,57.141,24
    c28.572,0,28.572-24,57.142-24c28.57,0,28.57,24,57.141,24c28.572,0,28.572-24,57.143-24c28.569,0,28.569,24,57.138,24
    c28.57,0,28.57-24,57.14-24c28.57,0,28.57,24,57.139,24s28.569-24,57.14-24c28.57,0,28.57,24,57.14,24c28.572,0,28.572-24,57.145-24
    s28.572,24,57.145,24c28.571,0,28.571-24,57.143-24c28.572,0,28.572,24,57.145,24c28.573,0,28.573-24,57.146-24
    c28.571,0,28.571,24,57.143,24c28.573,0,28.573-24,57.146-24c28.573,0,28.573,24,57.146,24c28.574,0,28.574-24,57.149-24
    s28.575,24,57.149,24" /> </svg>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/" x="0px" y="0px" width="960px" height="200px" viewBox="120 -87.5 960 200" overflow="visible" enable-background="new 120 -87.5 960 200"
  xml:space="preserve">
  <path id="wave2" fill="none" stroke="#E74267" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M0,0.5c14.633,0,14.633,24,29.266,24c14.632,0,14.632-24,29.265-24
    c14.636,0,14.636,24,29.27,24c14.633,0,14.633-24,29.265-24c14.635,0,14.635,24,29.268,24c14.635,0,14.635-24,29.269-24
    c14.633,0,14.633,24,29.267,24c14.633,0,14.633-24,29.267-24s14.634,24,29.266,24c14.635,0,14.635-24,29.269-24s14.634,24,29.268,24
    s14.634-24,29.269-24c14.634,0,14.634,24,29.269,24c14.633,0,14.633-24,29.268-24c14.631,0,14.631,24,29.262,24
    c14.633,0,14.633-24,29.266-24c14.632,0,14.632,24,29.266,24c14.631,0,14.631-24,29.263-24c14.634,0,14.634,24,29.266,24
    c14.636,0,14.636-24,29.269-24c14.635,0,14.635,24,29.268,24s14.633-24,29.266-24s14.633,24,29.266,24s14.633-24,29.268-24
    c14.633,0,14.633,24,29.266,24c14.637,0,14.637-24,29.271-24s14.635,24,29.268,24c14.635,0,14.635-24,29.27-24s14.635,24,29.27,24
    s14.635-24,29.27-24s14.635,24,29.27,24s14.635-24,29.27-24c14.633,0,14.633,24,29.266,24c14.635,0,14.635-24,29.27-24
    s14.635,24,29.27,24s14.635-24,29.271-24s14.637,24,29.271,24c14.639,0,14.639-24,29.275-24s14.637,24,29.273,24
    c14.639,0,14.639-24,29.277-24s14.639,24,29.277,24" /> </svg>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="960px" height="200px" viewBox="100.641 -75.5 960 200" overflow="visible" enable-background="new 100.641 -75.5 960 200" xml:space="preserve">
  <path id="wave3" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M1161.282,0.5c-19.359,0-19.359,48-38.719,48
    c-19.355,0-19.355-48-38.713-48c-19.355,0-19.355,48-38.715,48c-19.355,0-19.355-48-38.711-48s-19.355,48-38.711,48
    c-19.354,0-19.354-48-38.707-48c-19.355,0-19.355,48-38.713,48c-19.355,0-19.355-48-38.711-48s-19.355,48-38.713,48
    c-19.354,0-19.354-48-38.709-48s-19.355,48-38.709,48s-19.354-48-38.709-48c-19.354,0-19.354,48-38.709,48
    c-19.354,0-19.354-48-38.709-48c-19.354,0-19.354,48-38.71,48c-19.353,0-19.353-48-38.707-48c-19.353,0-19.353,48-38.706,48
    s-19.353-48-38.705-48s-19.352,48-38.704,48c-19.353,0-19.353-48-38.705-48c-19.355,0-19.355,48-38.709,48
    c-19.355,0-19.355-48-38.708-48c-19.356,0-19.356,48-38.71,48s-19.354-48-38.708-48s-19.354,48-38.708,48
    c-19.355,0-19.355-48-38.708-48c-19.355,0-19.355,48-38.709,48s-19.354-48-38.709-48s-19.354,48-38.709,48S19.354,0.5,0,0.5" />
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [svg plus css animation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41757925/7394871) от участника  [@pcuvi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444913/pcuvi).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41757925/svg-plus-css-animation/41761166#41761166

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если вы хотите, постепенно сгладить линии у волн, то можно просто анимировать их уменьшение  от 1 до 0.

```css
body {
  width: 960px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
}


#wave1 {
  animation: popup 5s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes popup {
  0% {
    transform: translate( -500px, 0) scale(1, 1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(400px, 0) scale(1, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="960px" height="200px" viewBox="91.43 -87.5 960 200" overflow="visible" enable-background="new 91.43 -87.5 960 200" xml:space="preserve">
  <path id="wave1" fill="none" stroke="#2E2925" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M0,24.5c28.57,0,28.57-24,57.141-24c28.57,0,28.57,24,57.141,24
    c28.572,0,28.572-24,57.142-24c28.57,0,28.57,24,57.141,24c28.572,0,28.572-24,57.143-24c28.569,0,28.569,24,57.138,24
    c28.57,0,28.57-24,57.14-24c28.57,0,28.57,24,57.139,24s28.569-24,57.14-24c28.57,0,28.57,24,57.14,24c28.572,0,28.572-24,57.145-24
    s28.572,24,57.145,24c28.571,0,28.571-24,57.143-24c28.572,0,28.572,24,57.145,24c28.573,0,28.573-24,57.146-24
    c28.571,0,28.571,24,57.143,24c28.573,0,28.573-24,57.146-24c28.573,0,28.573,24,57.146,24c28.574,0,28.574-24,57.149-24
    s28.575,24,57.149,24" />
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41761166/7394871) от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>